# Entity Framework Core 1.1 で[Table]属性が効かない？

Tags: c#, entity-framework

既にあるDBのtable名が"mytable"だとして、次のように属性つけていますが認識してくれません。
どうすればいいでしょうか？

Hoge.cs

```
[Table("mytable")]
public class Hoge {
...
}
```

MyDbContext.cs

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
public DbSet<Hoge> Hoge { get; set; }
...
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
```

内部例外

```
Table 'mydatabase.hoge' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

二つしか思い当たりませんが、

1つ目は、DbContextのOnModelCreatingメソッドで、

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Hoge>().ToTable("Hoge");
```

のようなコードを入いれている可能性。
こちらの方が優先されるので、ToTableは削除する必要があります。

2つ目は、Hoge.csで誤ったTable属性を使っている可能性。

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Table属性は↑のを使用していますでしょうか？